# Does Java have plan that default method (java8) Substitute for Abstract Class?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, abstract-class, default-method

Does Java have plan that `default method` substitute for  `Abstract Class`?
I could not find a real case to use default method instead of Abstract?

Comment: Why not? Consider adding functionality to an interface without breaking its implementors.

Comment: You'd have to ask those lovely people over at Oracle.  I don't think the Stack Overflow community can answer questions about what plans Oracle may have.

Comment: @DavidWallace that is why stackoverflow exist? right?  The reason behind the topic is that if Abstract Class is still neccessary after default method implementation comes with jaava8?

Comment: But that's not what you asked.

Comment: Yes, it's still necessary. Default methods in interfaces pose design issues due to limitations of interfaces.

Comment: @DavidWallace The "lovely people over at Oracle" are members of the StackOverflow community. http://stackoverflow.com/users/3553087/brian-goetz, http://stackoverflow.com/users/1441122/stuart-marks and others.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I will be extremely surprised if Brian Goetz or Stuart Marks answers this question.  If I want information from Oracle, I'll email someone at Oracle - I won't post a question here in the hope that they see it.

Comment: @DavidWallace Oracle guys have no need to answer this one in particular only because answers are already available. Asking them in private email about it would be far less appropriate. You assume OP wants information "from Oracle", but that is not factually correct. OP wants his doubt answered and, judging by the answers below, he very well succeeded.

Comment: I think, the technical aspects are already discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19998454/2711488). If it is about intentions and plans, you may refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30000456/2711488)

Comment: @DavidWallace Surprise, surprise. :-)

Comment: Also related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24016962/java8-why-is-it-forbidden-to-define-a-default-method-for-a-method-from-java-lan/24026292#24026292

Comment: Touché.  And I am delighted to see both of you gentlemen participating here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default methods can't substitute abstract classes, as abstract classes can (and often do) have fields. Interfaces can only contain behaviour and not state, which is unlikely to change in the future as multiple inheritance of state in Java is seen (rightly or wrongly) as evil.

They can also have `final` methods, which is another thing you can't mimic with `default` methods.

If anything, interfaces with default methods resemble [traits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trait_(computer_programming)) rather than abstract classes, but the match isn't perfect. Using interfaces as traits is something that has to be done very carefully and knowing the limitations they come with. (Such as any implementing class can override a `default` method, potentially ruining the trait.)

More on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28681737/java-8-default-methods-as-traits-safe).

Comment: Java 9 will have private methods (as abstract classes do), though Java 8 doesn't.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: the `private` methods in interfaces only help sharing code between different always-`public` `default` or `static` methods. That’s different from publishing methods with access control, i.e. declare them `protected` or package-private. Note that the support for `private` methods in interfaces is already de-facto in Java 8, as lambda expressions get compiled into `private` methods, this also holds for lambda expressions contained in `default` or `static` interface methods.

Comment: @Holger private methods in interface will allow the code to be shared between public methods and extracted from them to simplify them.

Comment: @Peter Lawrey: that’s what I wanted to say; they won’t change, how the interface looks like from the outside.

Comment: @Holger agreed, it only makes sense to improve the readability of the code/maintenance.

Answer (score 8):

There are no such plans, which you can derive from comparing the already documented intentions, which differ from the implications of such a plan:

[Stuart Marks writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30000456/2711488):

> The main goal is to allow *interface evolution*, that is, the addition of new methods. If a new method is added to an interface, existing classes that implement the interface would be missing an implementation, which would be incompatible. To be compatible, an implementation has to come from somewhere, so it is provided by default methods.
>
> …
>
> The main intent of a Java interface is to [specify a contract](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/createinterface.html) that any class can implement without having to alter its position in the class hierarchy. It's true that, prior to Java 8, interfaces were purely abstract. However, this is not an essential property of interfaces. Even when default methods are included, an interface at its heart still specifies a contract upon the implementing class. The implementing class can override default methods, so the class is still in complete control of its implementation. (Note also that [default methods cannot be final](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23453287/why-is-final-not-allowed-in-java-8-interface-methods/23476994#23476994).)

and [Brian Goetz writes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28684917/2711488):

> The proximate reason for adding default methods to interfaces was to support *interface evolution*, …
>
> Here are some use cases that are well within the design goals:
>
> - Interface evolution.  Here, we are adding a new method to an existing interface, which has a sensible default implementation in terms of existing methods on that interface.  An example would be adding the `forEach` method to `Collection`, where the default implementation is written in terms of the `iterator()` method.
> - "Optional" methods.  Here, the designer of an interface is saying "Implementors need not implement this method if they are willing to live with the limitations in functionality that entails".  For example, `Iterator.remove` was given a default which throws `UnsupportedOperationException`; since the vast majority of implementations of `Iterator` have this behavior anyway, the default makes this method essentially optional.  (If the behavior from `AbstractCollection` were expressed as defaults on `Collection`, we might do the same for the mutative methods.)
> - Convenience methods.  These are methods that are strictly for convenience, again generally implemented in terms of non-default methods on the class.  The `logger()` method in your first example is a reasonable illustration of this.
> - Combinators.  These are compositional methods that instantiate new instances of the interface based on the current instance.  For example, the methods `Predicate.and()` or `Comparator.thenComparing()` are examples of combinators.

Note that these do not target the primary domain of abstract classes, like providing a skeleton implementation. Besides the [technical differences](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19998454/2711488), abstract classes are semantically different as they bear design decisions about *how* to implement the functionality, which interfaces, even with `default` methods, should not. E.g. a well-known example is the `List` interface, for which two fundamentally different abstract classes exist, `AbstractList` and `AbstractSequentialList` and the choice of subclasses either or implementing `List` entirely different should not be foreclosed by the interface. So the `List` interface defines the contract and can never be a substitute for an abstract class, which provides a particular base implementation.

Comment: Interesting that both Marks and Goetz have mentioned interface evolution, and that Marks has labelled this "the main goal".  I can't help thinking that if this were true, they would have simply changed the language so that interface methods _don't have to be implemented_ in an implementation of the interface.  Unimplemented methods could simply do nothing, and return null (if their return type is a reference type) or the right flavour of zero or false (if their return type is a primitive).  I can't see how such a change in the language would break anything.  And I would have greatly ...

Comment: ... preferred it to the whole "default methods" mess, which (1) is just begging to be horribly misused, (2) actually makes it much harder to find the "actual implementation" of a method in a class that implements loads of interfaces and (3) don't get me started on diamond inheritance.  With all due respect to @StuartMarks, I really don't understand the first paragraph of his that you've quoted here.

Comment: @David Wallace: I’m very happy, not to encounter such poor man’s `default` methods which are actually unusable, without a chance for the client code to find out. The task of finding the implementation is as easy as clicking on the method in an IDE, not that it matters as you should develop against the contract, regardless of where the method is implemented, and the “diamond inheritance” isn’t an actual problem as the language forbids ambiguous inheritance. And while interface evolution is an important goal it is *not* the only goal. Consider [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19998622/2711488)…

Answer (score 7):

Other answers, and links to additional materials, have already adequately covered the technical differences between interfaces and abstract classes. What hasn't been covered well is why to use one over the other.

Consider two different ways to use a class or interface in Java: as a *caller* or as a *subclasser*. A caller has an object reference and can call `public` methods and access `public` fields via that reference. A subclasser can also access, call, and override `protected` members of the superclass. Classes can have `protected` members, but interfaces cannot.

A common question seems to be, now that we have default methods, why do we need abstract classes? A default method is part of what the interface presents to callers. A `protected` method on a class is not available to callers; it is only available to subclassers. Thus, if you want to share implementation with subclassers, then use a class (or abstract class) and define `protected` members and fields.

**The `protected` mechanism allows a class to communicate with subclassers, distinct from the way it communicates with callers.**

But the OP asks the opposite question: why would one use default methods in preference to abstract classes?  In the situation where you actually have a choice (i.e., your abstraction doesn't require state, or protected methods, or any of the things that abstract classes have that interfaces do not), interfaces with default methods are far less constraining than abstract classes.  You can only inherit from one class; you can inherit from many interfaces.  So interfaces with default methods can behave like stateless traits or mixins, allowing you to inherit behavior from multiple interfaces.

Given that interfaces and abstract classes are used for different purposes, there is no plan to remove or replace anything.

Answer (score 5):

One of the reasons why default methods in interfaces were introduced was to allow adding new methods to the JDK interfaces.

Without this feature once a class has been compiled with a specific version of an interface no new methods can be added to this interface. With the default methods in interfaces feature interfaces can be changed.